# Testing localised site

Tags: asp.net, testing, localization

Am developing an page that redirects users to the appropriate page depending on what country they are visiting the site from. Is there a way I can trick the site or the browser into thinking I'm visiting from different countries?

Thanks

Edit----
Location is based on IP address. Am developing in Visual Studio 2010 and ideally need to be able to test the location whilst debugging.

Comment: how do you check the country? Browser or OS language?

Answer (score 1):

If you use a proxy, then yes . you can trick the website that you are from an other country.